# Did I solve this logarithmic equation problem corectly and if so why doesn't commpleting the square work?

Tags: logarithms

1. $\log(x) + \log(x-1) = \log(4x)$
2. $\log((x)(x-1))=\log(4x)$ use the law of logs
3. $\log(x^2 -x)=\log(4x)$ distribute the x
4. $x^2-x = 4x$ use the one to one nature of logs
5. $x^2 = 5x$ add x
6. $x=5$ Divide by x

Comment: You might indicate at the last step how you know $x\neq0$, but otherwise, it's okay.  Formatting tip:  if you use `$\log$` instead of `$log$` your posts will look better.  Same goes for other standard functions like $\sin$, $\max$ etc.

Comment: Steps 1,2,3,4,5 are okay. Then go on with $x(x-5)=0$ so that $x=5$ or $x=0$. Substituting in the original expressions shows that $x=5$ is indeed a solution and that $x=0$ falls off because $\log$ is only defined on positive numbers. Division by an unkown $x$ is tricky and should be avoided.

Comment: $x=5$ is correct. What do you mean by completing the square?

Comment: You can divide by $x$ if you know than it can't be zero. $x=5$ is the solution. What is your question?

Comment: You could also have started by writing $\log(4x)=\log(4)+\log(x)$ and subtracting $\log(x)$ from both sides.

Comment: @imranfat when I do that I get x = 2.5 after completing the square

Comment: @amWhy. Realize it now, deleted.

Comment: @HiShin. No need to complete the square, just factor.

Comment: HiShin  No, you get $x(x-5) = 0 \implies (x=0 \text{ or } x=5)$. Since $x = 0$ is not in the domain of the original function (because $\log(0)$ is undefined, only $x=5$ remains as a valid solution, just as drhab wrote in the second comment below your post.

Comment: Can you indicate which step you wish to "complete the square"...

Comment: Cool I get that stuff, however why doesn't completing the square work? even if its unnecessary, shouldn't it still work?

Comment: @HiShin Do you mean while solving $x^2=5x$?

Comment: @Saket Gurjar when I get to step 4. I can either add $\ x $ or subtract $\ 4x $ , if I subtract $\ 4x $ then I get $\ x^2 - 5x = 0$. why doesn't completing the square work to tell me what $\ x $ is

Comment: THANK YOU. I forgot to balance the equation....

Comment: @Hishin I've expanded my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct except with the omission of the justification of why division by $x$ is permissible in the second last step. Division is only allowed when $x\neq 0$. Here you must state that the original equation disallows $x=0$ as then $\log x$ would be undefined, so division by (nonzero) $x$ is justified. Then your solution would be completely correct.

As to your question about completing the square, it certainly "works":

$x^2 = 5x \\ \implies x^2 - 5x = 0 \\ \implies x^2 - 5x + (\frac 52)^2 - \frac{25}4 = 0 \\  \implies (x-\frac 52)^2 = \frac {25}4 \\ \implies x-\frac 52 = \pm \frac 52 \\ \implies x=0 \ \mathrm{or} \ x=5$

(and you reject $0$ as $\log 0$ is undefined).

But this is completely and utterly unnecessary in solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Completing the square method does work.

$$x^2=5x$$

$$x^2-5x+\frac{25}{4}=\frac{25}{4}$$

$$\left(x-\frac{5}{2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^2$$

$$(x)(x-5)=0$$

Here remember to discard the $x=0$ solution.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should indicate that $\ x$ $\neq$ 0
if that is true then division by X is allowed

Secondly, completing the square does work make sure that you are balancing the equation.

Both Saket Gurjar and Deepak answer the question correctly